# Finding the entity with the highest value in the embedded ID with a custom JPA query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My entity has an composite id consisting of two properties, version and id. I want to find the entity with the highest version. In JPA limit is not possible, how can i restrict my current return to exactly one entity?

```
@Entity
public class GatewayConfigEntity implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private GatewayConfigEntityId gatewayConfigId;
}

@Embeddable
public class GatewayConfigIdEntity implements Serializable {
    private int version;
    private UUID resourceId;
}
```

```
@Query("select config from GatewayConfigEntity config where config.deviceId=:deviceId order by config.gatewayConfigId.version desc")
Set<GatewayConfigEntity> findLatestGatewayConfigForDevice(UUID deviceId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("select config from GatewayConfigEntity config where config.deviceId=:deviceId order by config.gatewayConfigId.version desc")
Set<GatewayConfigEntity> findLatestGatewayConfigForDevice(UUID deviceId, Pageable page);
```

you invoke the previous query requesting the first page with only one element per page

```
Set<GatewayConfigEntity> latestGateways = repository.findLatestGatewayConfigForDevice(deviceId, PageRequest.of(0,1));
GatewayConfigEntity latestGateway = latestGateways.isEmpty() ? null : latestGateways.iterator().next();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `Page<GatewayConfigEntity>` for method return type instead of `Set<GatewayConfigEntity>` when you work with Pageable?